# How to ignore non visible elements in xPath?

Tags: xpath

I want to ignore elements from my xpath query that are not visible, either because they **or any of their ancestors** are `display:none`.

I tried the below, but it's including elements which non displayable ancestors

```
//button[
            not(contains(@style,'display:none'))
            and
            not(ancestor::div[contains(@style,'display:none')])
            and
            contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz'), 'acept')

            ]
            "
```

Comment: Can you share HTML-code sample as well?

Comment: Hi @JaSON , you can check in https://www.forocoches.com/ - you will see there are 2 ocurrences, but one of the button is under a div with class sd-cmp-3b4Fj, which is display:none

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply this

```
//*[not(ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@style,'display: none;')])]
```